How to point an outdated master branch to the newest commit without carrying the chnages?
The repository I am working on was not maintained properly and the master branch was abandoned a few years back. I want to point it to the newest changes without carrying any changes from the old master.
This is how it looks like, where Branch B3 and Master point to a same commit
 A---B---C---D---E ................ --Curr_Branch
      \
       B1---B2---B3/Master

This is what I would like to achieve
 A---B---C---D---E ................ --Curr_Branch / Master
      \
       B1---B2---B3


Just move the pointer... on a local brach: git branch -f master the-commit-you-want. On a remote repo: git push -f some-remote the-commit-you-want:master. That way (local or remote) the pointer moves and sets itself exactly at that commit, regardless of where it was pointing to before. I assume it is not a problem in this case because you say that master was basically abandoned, right? So you do not have other people with changes on top of it so it should be fine.

@eftshift0 is there a benefit to using git branch -f over git reset --hard?

@evolutionxbox git reset --hard is primarily an action on the current working tree, so needs you to check out the branch, not have any local changes you care about, etc. git branch -f is an action directly on the branch reference, so only needs a copy of the repository, and doesn't affect anything else you're working on.

@eftshift0 That should have been an answer, IMHO. I've posted it as a Community Wiki answer below (i.e. I'm not taking credit). If you want to post and take credit, let me know and I'll delete the CW.

@IMSoP To be fair, git branch -f has the inverse (and arguably less inconvenient) constraint: you must not be on said branch to execute the command.

@IMSoP It's an nth-plicate, actually... that's why I did not provide it as an answer.

@eftshift0 In that case, even if you don't know the exact duplicate, a more useful comment would be "I'm pretty sure this has been answered already, try searching for '...'" Answering in the comments just leaves the question in a mess, because the asker goes away happy, but doesn't learn how the site works; and the question stays "unanswered".

[Lightly edited from comment by eftshift0]
Just move the pointer

To move the branch on a local working copy: git branch -f master the-commit-you-want
To move the branch on a remote repo: git push -f some-remote the-commit-you-want:master

That way (local or remote) the pointer moves and sets itself exactly at that commit, regardless of where it was pointing to before.
I assume it is not a problem in this case because you say that master was basically abandoned, right? So you do not have other people with changes on top of it so it should be fine.

I would use a hard reset here:
# from the Master branch
git fetch origin  # optional
git reset --hard origin/Curr_Branch

This will point the legacy Master branch to the Curr_Branch branch.  If your local current might not be the latest, then do a git fetch origin before the hard reset.
